# Does there exist a magma where every element has a left cube root but not every element has a right cube root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Let $(M,*)$ be a magma. $x$ is said to be a left cube root of $y$ if $(x*x)*x=y$. $x$ is said to be a right cube root of $y$ if $x*(x*x)=y$. Does there exist a magma where every element has a left cube root, but not every element has a right cube root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the law (written without any sign):
$$
\begin{array}{r|cc}
  & 0 & 1\\\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(00)0 &= 00 = 0\ ,\\
(11)1 &= 01 =1\ ,\\[2mm]
0(00) &= 00 = 0\ ,\\
1(11) &= 10 = 0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is the Boolean operation $\lnot x\land y$.